# Convert floating point to scientific notation in C (nonstandard format)?

Tags: c, format, point, floating, scientific-notation

I need to convert a floating point number to the following nonstandard format:
"a floating point number F (in standard decimal exponential format), followed by the string
    times 10 to the power,
followed by an integer K."

Is there a way to extract the  exponent from e% or a function similar to frexp()?

E.g.: 3349.25 should be "3.34925 times 10 to the power 3"

Comment: Provide what is your expected output with an example

Comment: Lacking a better plan, I would probably `snprintf` the `float` using `%e` and then simply work with the string you get from that. This isn't massively pretty, but it will work.

Comment: General description: the scientific notation exponent of `10` will be the integer part of log base 10 of your original number. Then the scientific notation "mantissa" will be the original number divided by 10 to that power. You can use `%f` to print that portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a decimal equivalent of frexp yourself quite easily. The code you need looks something like this:

```
int exponent = (int)log10(fabs(d));
double mantissa = d / pow(10, exponent);
printf("%f X 10^%d\n", mantissa, exponent);
```

First we determine the exponent by taking the base-10 logarithm of the absolute value of your number. (We need `fabs` because `log10` requires a positive argument.) The cast rounds towards zero, which is, conveniently, what we need. Then we normalize the mantissa by dividing.

This doesn't handle d==0 (or infinity or NaN), the division will introduce some error into the result, and I haven't tested it with small numbers or negative numbers, but this should give you something to start from.

Comment: for numbers between 0 and 1, rounding towards zero gives wrong results, e.g. `(int)log10(0.12)=0`. Floor may be better suited

Answer (score 2):

I like the OP approach to let `printf()`, using the `"%e"` format, to do the heavy lifting.

There are *many* issues with `double` to string conversion that existing functions already handle nicely.  (INF, Nan, -0, rounding, negatives).  OP use of `frexp()`, `power()` typically have troubles near values a power of 10 do to rounding and and finite precision.

OP is fuzzy on how much precision given only 1 example.  `power(0.5, 100)` would need 100 digits.  Let's limit it to DBL_DIG, rather than use the `%e` default of 6. (which is really 7 digits, just 6 after the DP.)

```
char *Heyhey_Notation(char *dest, double x) {
  static const char Times[] = " times 10 to the power ";
  char buffer[3 + DBL_DIG + sizeof(Times) + 20 + 1];

  sprintf(buffer, "%.*e", DBL_DIG, x);
  char *e = strchr(buffer, 'e');  // find exponent position
  if (e) {
    char *zero = e;
    while (zero[-1] == '0') zero--; 
    *zero = '\0'; // OP wants excess zeros trimmed.
    int power = atoi(&e[1]);  // trim excess zeros by converting to int
    sprintf(dest, "%s%s%d", buffer, Times, power);
    }
  else {
    strcpy(dest, buffer);
  }
  return dest;
}

int main() {
  char buf[100];
  puts(Heyhey_Notation(buf, 3349.25));
  puts(Heyhey_Notation(buf, -0.0));
  puts(Heyhey_Notation(buf, 123));
  puts(Heyhey_Notation(buf, -1234567890.0/9999999999.0));
  puts(Heyhey_Notation(buf, -1/0.0));
  puts(Heyhey_Notation(buf, atof("nan")));
  return 0;
}

3.34925 times 10 to the power 3
-0. times 10 to the power 0
1.23 times 10 to the power 2
-1.234567890123457 times 10 to the power -1
-inf
nan
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info but I just needed to write float in a different format and the answer from pburka worked out well.

Comment: @Heyhey Heyhey Thought you wanted "3.34925 X 10^3" as _posted_ and not "3.349250 X 10^3".  Aside from 0.0 trouble, with |input| < 1.0 the other method gives a leading digit of 0.  Glad the other solution works well for you - thanks for the up-vote,